# General solution of $a^{-x} = \log_a(x)$

Tags: logarithms, recreational-mathematics

Is it possible to solve $a^{-x} = \log_a(x)$ with $x$ in terms of $a$?

Comment: It's possible to solve the following. $x^{-a}=\log_ax.$

Comment: Seems even the natural log problem has no closed form https://math.stackexchange.com/q/993944/399263

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was said - it cannot be solved analytically. But the function $x=x(a)$   can be solved for numerically and plotted.
[image]

The function is defined only for $a>0$. It has a discontinuity at $a=1$. It has a maximum at around $a\approx1.8$ where $x\approx1.3$. As $a\to\infty$, $x$ goes to $1$

Comment: It looks particularly smooth, should be approximable piecewise with simple functions.

Comment: I agree with you. It can be easily approximated smoothly with splines or even with polynomials.