# How to solve $e^x \ln(x) = a$?

Tags: closed-form, lambert-w

I was wondering if it was possible to solve equations of the form  $e^x \ln(x) = a, \;a > 0$  in terms of the Lambert $W$ function $W(x)$?

I understand that fixed point iteration or the Newton-Rhapson method would work here but am wondering if there is another technique that could give a closed form.

The question [Solving $\ln(x) = e^{-x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993944/solving-lnx-e-x) already exists and is equivalent to the case where $a = 1$, but all the answers point to using approximate methods or say that solutions are normally involve the Lambert $W$ function but don’t give any explicit answers.

Comment: We cannot solve this with Lambert W.

Comment: @GEdgar Why so certain? Do we have a rigorous/intuitive reason to completely dismiss the possibility?

Comment: I do not have an answer. One direction you could explore is a field extension to the complex plane, but I do not know what if anything you will find.

Comment: Suppose $ax=ln x\Rightarrow ln x /a=W(1)=x\Rightarrow ln(W(1))=aW(1)$. Thus only possible a's are $ln(W_n(1))/W_n(1)$ ?

Comment: You could also write $x=b\ln x\Rightarrow b\ln x=W(ab)=x\Rightarrow x=f(x)=W(ax/\ln x)=W(aW(ax/\ln x)/\ln(W(ax/\ln x)))=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f^n(x)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider [solutions in closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Closed-form_number).

$$e^x\ln(x)=a$$

**1.) No algebraic solutions except $1$ for algebraic $a$**

According to [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture), we have $\forall\ 0,1\neq x\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\colon$ $\text{trdeg}_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}\left(x,\ln(x),e^x\right)=2$. That means: $\ln(a_0),e^{a_0}$ are $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$-algebraically independent for each algebraic $a_0\neq 0,1$. That means, your equation cannot have algebraic solutions except $1$ for algebraic $a$.

**2.) No general elementary solutions**

According to the theorem of [Ritt 1925], that is proved also in [Risch 1979], the function $f\colon x\mapsto e^x\ln(x)$ seems not to have partial inverses that are [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) for non-discrete domains of $f$.

But that doesn't say if solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) are possible for single $a$.

[[Risch 1979] Risch, R. H.: Algebraic Properties of the Elementary Functions of Analysis. Amer. J. Math. 101 (1979) (4) 743-759](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373917?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

[[Ritt 1925] Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/)

**3.) Solutions in terms of Hyper Lambert W**

$$e^x\ln(x)=a$$

$$x\to e^z: e^{e^z}(z+2k\pi i)=a\ \ \ \ \ (k\in\mathbb{Z})$$

$$-\pi<\text{Im}(z)\le\pi:$$

$$e^{e^z}z=a$$

This equation can be solved by Hyper Lambert W:

[Galidakis, I. N.: On solving the p-th complex auxiliary equation $f^{(p)}(z)=z$. Complex Variables 50 (2005) (13) 977-997](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233129552_On_solving_the_p-th_complex_auxiliary_equation_fpzz)

[Galidakis, I. N.: On some applications of the generalized hyper-Lambert functions. Complex Variables and Elliptic Equations 52 (2007) (12) 1101-1119](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233200491_On_some_applications_of_the_generalized_hyper-Lambert_functions)

Comment: Is the Lambert Hyperfunction a standard function?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Like Lambert W, Hyper Lambert W is a relation that is named, well desribed and that can be used in many ways. What else is a standard function? Hyper Lambert W is new, therefore it's not that widespread yet. Galidakis 2007 gives a MAPLE algorithm for Hyper Lambert W.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I wouldn't say Lambert Hyperfunction, because the term Hyperfunction is already taken: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfunction

Comment: For Hyper-Lambert W, see also Katsimpiri, Ch.; Nastou, P. E.; Pardalos, P. M.; Stamatiou, Y. C.: The Ubiquitous Lambert Function and its Classes in Sciences and Engineering. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-31317-7_16

Answer (score 2):

If $a=-1$, there is a solution that uses Lambert twice.

$$\begin{align}
e^x\ln(x)&=-1\\
\ln(x)&=-1\cdot e^{-x}\\
x\ln(x)&=-x\cdot e^{-x}\\
W(x\ln(x))&=W(-x\cdot e^{-x})\\
\ln(x) &= -x\\
x &= e^{-x}\\
e^xx &= 1\\
x&=W(1)
\end{align}$$

Maybe you can modify this to handle general values of $a$. To be honest, I have doubts. Somehow you would need to decompose $a$ in such a way that it could be absorbed partly on the left side of the equation and partly on the right side of the equation to get each side in the form $ze^z$.

With this exact solution for $a=-1$, you could also possibly find approximate solutions more quickly for $a$ near $-1$.

Comment: A slightly shorter way: from $\ln(x) = -x$, $x = e^{-x}$, $x e^x=1$, $W(x)=1$.

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks! I updated it to go that way.

Comment: Interestingly, the computer algebra systems cannot find this closed-form solution.

Answer (score 1):

Beside Lambert hyperfunction, there is no explicit solution for the zero of function
$$f(x)=e^x\, \log(x)-a$$ and a numerical method would be required and, as usual, a decent initial guess.

$f(x)$ is a very stiff function and it will be much easier to look for the zero of
$$g(x)=x+\log(\log(x))-\log(a)$$ which is quite linear as soon as $x > 2$

Since we can *approximate* $e^x\, \log(x)$ by $x^k\,e^x$, then select $k$ such that
$$\Phi(k)=\int_1^t \Big[\log (\log (x))-k \log (x)\Big]^2\,dx$$ be minimum. For $t=20$ (this corresponds to $a \sim 1.45\times 10^9$), the optimum value of $k$ is around $0.3494$ which is very close $\frac 7 {20}$. This gives as a first estimate
$$x_0=\frac{7}{20} W\left(\frac{20 }{7}a^{20/7}\right)$$ With this, start Newton iterations with
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n (\log (x_n) (\log (a)-\log (\log (x_n)))+1)}{x_n \log (x_n)+1}$$

For illustration purposes, let $a=10^p$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 p & x_0 & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 2.0511456 & 2.3979568 &  2.4241905 \\
 2 & 4.1104351 & 4.2372540 &  4.2377334 \\
 3 & 6.2654856 & 6.2978641 &  6.2978744 \\
 4 & 8.4628503 & 8.4521448 &  8.4521453 \\
 5 & 10.683868 & 10.651835 &  10.651838 \\
 6 & 12.919940 & 12.877274 &  12.877277 \\
 7 & 15.166416 & 15.118952 &  15.118954 \\
 8 & 17.420504 & 17.371663 &  17.371665 \\
 9 & 19.680398 & 19.632289 &  19.632291 \\
 10 & 21.944864 & 21.898834 &  21.898835
\end{array}
\right)$$

So even if not perfectly exact, $x_1$ (which has a closed form) is *almost* the solution.